# Magento tax toggle

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I've been searching for some advice on this for a while. Is there a way to toggle the tax display in Magento (inc Tax, ex Tax). My client would like two radio buttons, one to show tax and one not to.

There's a couple of plugins but they don't seem to be tested past version 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento by default wraps prices in `<span>` elements with class `"price-excluding-tax"` or `"price-including-tax"`. You can just use javascript to show or hide them. For example, if you're using `jQuery`:

```
if(exTax radio button is clicked){
    jQuery('.price-including-tax').hide();
    jQuery('.price-excluding-tax').show();
}else{
    jQuery('.price-including-tax').show();
    jQuery('.price-excluding-tax').hide();
}
```

Also make sure Magento is configured to display both including and excluding Tax prices on the frontend.